# Connection Timeout Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, sucker-punch

I am getting following error on my application logs

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)
```

My application is required to create too many background workers. I am using `sucker-punch gem` for background jobs. I have implemented Rollbar tool to monitor application crashes and it is reporting

```
10 occurrences in 5 minutes: #8 ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)
```

I am not sure why is this happening but I can feel that some of my background jobs keeps on breaking time to time. At lot of places I am making DB connections using  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` command.

My DB pool size is set to `100`, and MYSQL statistics are:

```
Aborted_connects    **51088**
Connection_errors_accept    **0**
Connection_errors_internal  **0**
Connection_errors_max_connections   **0**
Connection_errors_peer_address  **8**
Connection_errors_select    **0**
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   **0**
Connections **1232264**
Max_used_connections    **115**
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   **0**
Ssl_client_connects **0**
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    **0**
Ssl_finished_connects   **0**
Threads_connected   **12**
```

Is something very wrong with the application? Also just an information to help debug the issue It's AWS EC2 CPU usage always remains very high above 80% all the time. I am using `m3.medium` instance.

Comment: You could start here, to check if there are any [memory leak](https://github.com/evan/bleak_house)

Comment: Could you post your `database.yml` and which `web server` are you using ?

Comment: Try running `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` in console.